# Problema em recuperar dados do firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Comecei recentemente a trabalhar com o Firebase e ainda estou aprendendo o que é possível ser feito lendo a documentação disponível. Mas um problema que estou tendo é em recuperar os dados dentro de uma função. O problema em questão é que para recuperar dados do banco no firebase é necessário criar um `ValueEventListener` que implementa os métodos `onDataChange` e `onCancelled` e dentro do método `onDataChange` recuperar os dados usando a variável do tipo `DataSnapshot`. O problema é que eu não consigo atribuir o resultado do método `getValue()` à minha variável `usuario` criada fora do método `OnDataChange`. Se eu crio a variável dentro do método, ele funciona sem problemas, mas com a variável fora eu não consigo fazer a atribuição. Acredito que isso seja causado porque os métodos são executados de forma assíncrona (eu acho). Alguém saberia alguma forma de eu conseguir fazer essa atribuição? Pois preciso dessa variável para executar outras tarefas no meu app. Segue abaixo o código referido:

```
public class FireBaseDB{

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public FireBaseDB(){
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    }

    public Usuario recuperarUsuarioDoBanco(String userId){

        mDatabase.child("users").child(userId);
        Usuario usuario;

        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class); //não funciona

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Ação Cancelada", databaseError.toException());

            }
        };
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(listener);

        return usuario;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o trecho onde você atribui mDatabase? Acredito que o problema seja na referência, mas sem a atribuição não posso afirmar.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática desculpe a demora, estava viajando e só voltei essa semana. Acabei de editar a pergunta com o trecho de código que você pediu.

Comment: Sem crise. Pode ser que o userId não foi colocado como chave. Por isso pode estar vindo nulo. Da uma olhada na estrutura do Firebase se a key da chave está igual. Tenta também ao invés de usar como child, aponta a referência direto pra key

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática acho que acabei explicando de forma errada o meu problema. O problema não é que a referência do usuário está sendo nula, o problema está no fato da própria IDE Android Studio mencionar que há um erro de sintaxe no código. Basicamente, mostra erro de sintaxe dizendo que a variável 'usuario' não existe. É como se o que está dentro do `onDataChange` não "enxergasse" o escopo de fora, que no caso é onde a variável está sendo criada. Tentei colocar  o modificador `final` na declaração da variável, mas continua com o mesmo problema. Você tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Coloca a variavel usuario como sendo uma global da classe. Veja se resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Para a IDE não mostrar o erro de sintaxe, você só precisa de declarar a variável `usuario` globalmente na classe, ao invés de declarar localmente no método:

```
public class FireBaseDB{

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private Usuario usuario;
```

Mas você terá um outro problema:
Os métodos de leitura do Firebase acontecem de forma assíncrona (numa outra Thread). Então no momento em que você faz o `return usuario`, essa variável ainda não foi inicializada.

Por isso, eu **não** recomendo criar uma classe(FireBaseDB) só para ler da base de dados. Faça a leitura diretamente na sua Activity ou Fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Esse problema pode ser solucionado de várias maneiras. A que eu mais utilizo é a seguinte:
Como eu não consigo controlar o Listener assíncrono, logo eu tento transforma-lo em síncrono, ou seja, controla-lo. Eu faço exatamente o seguinte.

```
public class FireBaseDB{

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public FireBaseDB(){
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    }

    public Usuario recuperarUsuarioDoBanco(String userId){

        mDatabase.child("users").child(userId);
        Usuario usuario;

        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Alimento o meu objeto
            usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class); 

            //E utilizo outra classe para "controlar" as informações do objeto
            UsuarioSPref usuario_sp = new UsuarioSPref();

        obj_Anuncios_sp.saveSP(objFirebaseAnuncios);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Ação Cancelada", databaseError.toException());

            }
        };
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(listener);

        return usuario;
    }

}
```

E na minha classe seguinte utilizo a classe SharePreference para armazenar as informações que recebo do objeto
Exemplo:

```
public class UsuarioSPref {
    //LibraryIO é a classe com diversos método do sharePreference que crie.
    private LibraryIO io = new LibraryIO(MyApplication.getAppContext());
    private String[] telaPrincipal = {"telaPrincipalNome", "telaPrincipalUrl", "telaPrincipalCliques", "telaPrincipal_imgUrl"};


    public boolean saveSP(ObjAnuncios objFBparametro) {

        Log.i("LINK_URL", "Método saveSP foi chamadao, listener de anúncios funcionando");

        io.setStringIO(telaPrincipal[0], objFBparametro.getNome());
        io.setStringIO(telaPrincipal[1], objFBparametro.getUrlWebPag());
        io.setIntIO(telaPrincipal[2], objFBparametro.getNumeroCliques());
        io.setStringIO(telaPrincipal[3], objFBparametro.getImgUrl());

        return true;
    }


}
```

Essa classe de armazenamento de dados primitivos é muito simples de utilizar e em nenhum problema chegará a ser um problema para você, pelo menos para mim, só me ajuda.
Assim, você poderá obter esse valores sempre que quiser sem se preocupar com o Listener e poderá obter os dados offline.

Espero ter ajudado!